# Invalid column name SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I have wasted hours trying to find what's incorrect in my code. Before adding  a new column in the table, it was ok but after that, whenever I submit my form, it gives me an error

> The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = userID ]

Here is my code:

```
con.Open();  
string query = "INSERT INTO PlayerTable 
(username ,password, picture, scoreL1, scoreL2, scoreL3, userID) 
VALUES
('" + @userName + "','" + @password + "',@picture," + @score1 
+ "," + @score2 + "," + @score3 + "," + @num + ")";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", a);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scoreL1", score1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scoreL2", score2);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scoreL3", score3);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", num);
                cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't it be:

```
string query =
  "INSERT INTO PlayerTable
   (username, password, picture, scoreL1, scoreL2, scoreL3, userID)
   VALUES(@userName, @password, @picture, @scoreL1, @scoreL2, @scoreL3, @userID)";
```

That is not `@score1` but `@scoreL1` and same for the others.

**Edit**

When you instantiate a new `SqlCeCommand`:

```
cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, con);
```

you essentially erase the paramaters you set earlier.
Move the instantiation above the parameter assignments:

```
cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", a);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scoreL1", score1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scoreL2", score2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scoreL3", score3);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", num);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: +1 . . . The other important thing is not to enclose the variable names in single quotes.

Comment: @user3624655: Do you have a column `userID` in the database table?

Comment: Can you show the layout/design/script of the table?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be surrounding your query parameters with quotes:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO PlayerTable 
 (username ,password, picture, scoreL1, scoreL2, scoreL3, userID) 
 VALUES(@userName, @password, @picture, @scoreL1, @scoreL2, @scoreL3, @userID )";
```

Additionally, you need to make sure your Parameter Names match the @ values.